# How to log outgoing HttpClient request?

Tags: c#, console-application, dotnet-httpclient, system.diagnostics, .net-4.6.1

I want to connect to REST Api, but it keeps returning `status code 400 (Bad Request)` no matter how I build the request.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

My question is, how can I debug my `https` request to the server ? I would like to see, how my HTTP Request looks like.

I tried to use `DiagnosticSource` class, so I created `Observer` classes and subscribe all listeners to it.

**Observer**

```
class Observer : IObserver<DiagnosticListener>
    {
        public void OnCompleted()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnError(Exception error)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnNext(DiagnosticListener value)
        {
            if (value.Name == "HttpHandlerDiagnosticListener")
            {
                value.Subscribe(new HttpClientObserver());
            }
        }
    }
```

**HttpClientObserver**

```
 class HttpClientObserver : IObserver<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
        {
            public void OnCompleted()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
    
            public void OnError(Exception error)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
    
            public void OnNext(KeyValuePair<string, object> value)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

**Main**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DiagnosticListener.AllListeners.Subscribe(new Diagnostic.Observer());

            // execute HttpClient methods do not throw any event to Observer
```

But no event was catched. What am I missing, does `HttpClient` support's `DiagnosticSource` (How can I recognize which classes do ?). What other solution I can use ?

Comment: If you are not looking for a permanent fixture, but just to debug this issue, you can use something like Fiddler to capture network traffic and see all of the details.

Comment: thank you for a tip, but I am not able to use these kind of tools. Anyway, can Fiddler inspect `https` requests ?

Comment: Yes, it can. Also Postman's interceptor.

Comment: Burp Suite can also track http/https traffic.

Comment: you need to await PostAsync. e.g HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

Comment: @Greg changing code to `async` made no change, still returns error 400 and did not threw any diagnostic event (only `System.Net.Http.Desktop` at the start of the console app execution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the best solutions is you use the [HttpClientToCurl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HttpClientToCurl/) extension in your codes for a better understanding of what send request exactly.
This extension will help you to see whatever is set in HttpClient in the form of a curl script.

**You have 3 ways to see script results:**

**1- Show in the console:**

```
httpClient.GenerateCurlInConsole(httpRequestMessage, null);
```

**2- Write in a file:**

```
httpClient.GenerateCurlInFile(httpRequestMessage, null);
```

**3- Put into a variable:**

```
string script = httpClient.GenerateCurlInString(httpRequestMessage, null);
```

Also, the HttpClientToCurl extension has attractive configs that you can see examples in [GitHub Address](https://github.com/amingolmahalle/HttpClientToCurlGenerator).
Moreover, you see the source of the project and see more examples.

This is a complete example when you want to send a request:

```
string requestBody = @"{""name"":""sara"",""requestId"":""10001001"",""amount"":20000}";
string requestUri = "api/test";
var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri);
httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}");

using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1213/v1/");

httpClient.GenerateCurlInConsole(
    httpRequestMessage,
    config =>
    {
        config.TurnOn = true;
        config.NeedAddDefaultHeaders = true;
        config.EnableCodeBeautification = false;
    });

 // Call PostAsync => await client.PostAsync(requestUri, httpRequest.Content);
```

The extension result is:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:1213/v1/api/test' -H 'Authorization: Bearer 4797c126-3f8a-454a-aff1-96c0220dae61' -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' -d '{""name"":""sara"",""requestId"":10001001,""amount"":20000}'"
```

Comment: A useful article for HttpClientToCurl extension: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-generate-curl-script-of-the-httpclient-in-net/

Answer (score 3):

When you're subscribing to the listener, you're create a new instance of a class. What you should do is create a private readonly instance. The DiagnosticListener is limited to capturing the start and end of the HTTP Client requests.

Below is a basic example, (with the code slightly refactored)

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var observer = new HttpClientGlobalListener();

    using (var subscription = DiagnosticListener.AllListeners.Subscribe(observer))
    {
        var results = await GetMyResultsAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(results);
    }
}

public static async Task<string> GetMyResultsAsync()
{
    var queryString = new StringContent("");

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("https://example/"), queryString);
        //var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response); // You could log response before raising error with "EnsureSuccessStatusCode".

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseBody;
    }
}

public class HttpClientGlobalListener : IObserver<DiagnosticListener>
{
    private readonly HttpClientInterceptor _interceptor = new HttpClientInterceptor();

    public void OnCompleted() { }

    public void OnError(Exception error) { }

    public void OnNext(DiagnosticListener listener)
    {
        listener.Subscribe(_interceptor);
    }
}

public class HttpClientInterceptor : IObserver<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
{
    public void OnCompleted() { }

    public void OnError(Exception error) { }

    public void OnNext(KeyValuePair<string, object> value)
    {
        if (value.Key == "System.Net.Http.Desktop.HttpRequestOut.Start")
        {
            var requestObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value.Value);
            Debug.WriteLine($"Request: {requestObj}");
        }
        else if (value.Key == "System.Net.Http.Desktop.HttpRequestOut.Stop")
        {
            var requestObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value.Value);
            Debug.WriteLine($"Response: {requestObj}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works :-) I can catch Request object now. But, I don't know how to convert the object to `raw HTTP Request` I am really sending or how to at least display data I am sending (`HttpContent` object) and where are the data located in the `raw HTTP Request` ?

Comment: The "value.Value" contains the HTTP Request. However it's wrapped in a dynamic object. I'm not sure how to query it. By using Json Serialize you can store the entire thing to string and read it. A hacky solution (in theory) is, once converted to string, you could remove the starting and ending brace bracket and deserialize it to the HttpRequest object.

Comment: I saved the `value.Value` to json file, that is okay. But the json does not contain much information, it does not even contain information if the request is get or post, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately json serializer value is not working outputting everything. You can see all the values in debugger. However I don't know how to query dynamic objects. I would recommend posting another question, specifically "How to cast Value.Value from object {<>f__AnonymousType1<System.Net.HttpWebRequest>} to  Value.Value.Request